# Extend Desktop to Monitor over LAN

Tags: networking, xorg, multiple-monitors

I want to make use of an old laptop by extending my the desktop from my main PC onto the  monitor of this other, old laptop over a LAN connection.

I've looked into [Xdmx/dmx](http://dmx.sourceforge.net), but the project seems to have been dead for a while.

Are there any other alternatives or will I have to cobble my own script together?

Comment: Have you tried remote desktop viewer ?

Comment: That doesn't allow me to extend the desktop, It's only a remote viewer.

Comment: Synergy is much easier if you don't need to drag windows eg if you just want to run a browser on the extra display.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Xdmx project is still active. You can download with:

```
sudo apt install xdmx
```

And here's a video on setting Xdmx

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YOzRCBGDVaE

And just to keep you posted that the DMX software has been integrated into the X.org server software.

Comment: do you know where I can get the source?

Comment: You can browse/download the source code from http://dmx.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/dmx/dmx/xc/

Comment: Thank you, I've managed to install it on Ubuntu 12 but on Ubuntu 13, there are a few dependency conflicts: libaudit1 vs libaudit0. I don't know whether it's possible to keep two version of a shared lib at the same time. Probably it does't matter, you just need one machine with Xdmx running but I wanted to extend the desktop of my other newer machine

Answer (score 1):

[Synergy](http://synergy-project.org/) is a nice program designed for something similar to what you want, it has intuitive GUI.

You won't be able to drag windows between displays though, since it does not use slave OS as another display device, but just sends keyboard/mouse input there.

Answer (score 1):

## Virtual Monitor Over VNC

[xdmx](http://dmx.sourceforge.net/) didn't worked for me, however I was able to get it working using [x11vnc](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/) by means of using my own code derived from the [VNC Virtual Display Linker](https://github.com/mrenrich84/vnc_virtual_display_linker) python code. I had a couple of issues with this code but I managed to get it working as shown below.

### Simplified Intructions:

Please be aware of the notes and considerations at the end of this answer.

1. **Definitions:** The "server" will be the computer which screen you want to extend, the "client" will be the computer (or tablet, any device able to deploy a VNC client) that you want to use as a screen.
2. **Required Software**: On the server install `x11vnc` and `gtf`, on the client install a vnc client.
3. You need to know client's screen size (we'll call them: `CLIENT_WIDTH`, `CLIENT_HEIGHT`) and the servers' screen size (we'll call them: `SERVER_WIDTH`, `SERVER_HEIGHT`).
4. In the server, run in a terminal `gtf CLIENT_WIDTH CLIENT_HEIGHT 60` (replace the `CLIENT_WIDTH` and `CLIENT_HEIGHT` with the corresponding values). As an example for `gtf CLIENT_WIDTH CLIENT_HEIGHT 60` is

```
# 1384x768 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 47.70 kHz; pclk: 86.62 MHz
Modeline "1384x768_60.00"  86.62  1384 1456 1600 1816  768 769 772 795  -HSync +Vsync
```

5. From the previous result copy what is in front of `Modeline`, (in this case `"1384x768_60.00"  86.62  1384 1456 1600 1816  768 769 772 795  -HSync +Vsync`) and use that as a parameter to `xrandr --newmode` command. For example, in this case, we'll have to run in the server `xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"  85.86  1368 1440 1584 1800  768 769 772 795  -HSync +Vsync`
6. In 5 we've created a newmode in `xrandr`, now we need to add it to the virtual screen, as follows `xrandr --addmode VIRTUAL1 "1368x768_60.00"` (please remember to use your own newly created mode name, which is the value including quotes in 5).
7. Run `x11vnc -usepw -nocursorshape -nocursorpos -noxinerama -solid -repeat -forever -clip CLIENT_WIDTHxCLIENT_HEIGHT+SERVER_WIDTH+0`. As an example: `x11vnc -usepw -nocursorshape -nocursorpos -noxinerama -solid -repeat -forever -clip 1368x768+1920+0`. This will create a VNC server in port `5900` you can connect to.
8. Lastly, connect to the server from you other computer (or any VNC client, recommended `krdc` for linux machines). You should be able to enjoy your extended screen now.

### Notes and considerations:

- In step 8, with krdc, it is recommended to use the "Medium Quality" option, even if you are on cable: both the "Low" and "High" quality options produce errors.
- I tried this over a WiFi network and it works properly, however on cable it's smoother.
- I had problems when starting the VNC server in step 7, the screen started to flicker and I couldn't see what I was doing on the screen. To fix this, I connected via the VNC server (the extended screen already works at this point), opened the `Displays` tool (the one that comes with the system where you can see the displays that are connected) and `Unify Outputs` then `Break Unified Outputs`
  (an example of this option in Kubuntu is shown below). Then everything worked.

[image: Unify Outputs]

Answer (score 0):

http://www.virtualgl.org even allows openGL!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.