# Tried to use xdmx and now I can't log in!

Tags: xorg

I was following the instructions on here: [Extend Desktop to Monitor over LAN](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136942/extend-desktop-to-monitor-over-lan)

And ran `startx -- /usr/bin/Xdmx :1 +xinerama -display :0.0 -display localhost:10.0 -norender -noglxproxy` on my new laptop over ssh with my old laptop as the client. This was meant to let me use my old laptop screen as an extended monitor.

It didn't work and all I got was a mouse on a black screen on my new laptop, so I restarted it but now I can't get past the login screen.

I tried uninstalling xdmx, openssh-server and even reinstalling xserver-xorg but nothing has helped.

Please help!

Answer (score 3):

It turns out there was a .Xauthority file in my home directory that did not show up with `locate` because it was owned by root. Deleting that did the trick!