# Use windows laptop as second screen to Ubuntu laptop

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, multiple-monitors, display

I'm using Ubuntu & I want to use my old windows 7 laptop as second monitor. I've come across a couple of questions around similar issue but none that are specific to my configuration. I'd really appreciate if someone can suggest a solution for this.

Comment: What do you mean with "use my old windows 7 laptop as second monitor"? Ubuntu is on another system?

Comment: I guess he wants to use his laptop's built-in screen as a secondary monitor using software. [Like this](http://www.maxivista.com/).

Comment: That's right.. I'm looking for something like maxivista but free

Answer (score 5):

These are some references to get you started:

[Extend Desktop to Monitor over LAN](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136942/extend-desktop-to-monitor-over-lan)

[Extend Linux Desktop to another X Windows Display](https://superuser.com/questions/71794/extend-linux-desktop-to-another-x-windows-display)

[DMX Homepage](https://dmx.sourceforge.net)

Answer (score 2):

## Virtual Monitor Over VNC

[xdmx](http://dmx.sourceforge.net/) didn't worked for me, however I was able to get it working using [x11vnc](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/) by means of using my own code derived from the [VNC Virtual Display Linker](https://github.com/mrenrich84/vnc_virtual_display_linker) python code. I had a couple of issues with this code but I managed to get it working as shown below.

### Simplified Intructions:

Please be aware of the notes and considerations at the end of this answer.

1. **Definitions:** The "server" will be the computer which screen you want to extend, the "client" will be the computer (or tablet, any device able to deploy a VNC client) that you want to use as a screen.
2. **Required Software**: On the server install `x11vnc` and `gtf`, on the client install a vnc client.
3. You need to know client's screen size (we'll call them: `CLIENT_WIDTH`, `CLIENT_HEIGHT`) and the servers' screen size (we'll call them: `SERVER_WIDTH`, `SERVER_HEIGHT`).
4. In the server, run in a terminal `gtf CLIENT_WIDTH CLIENT_HEIGHT 60` (replace the `CLIENT_WIDTH` and `CLIENT_HEIGHT` with the corresponding values). As an example for `gtf CLIENT_WIDTH CLIENT_HEIGHT 60` is

```
# 1384x768 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 47.70 kHz; pclk: 86.62 MHz
Modeline "1384x768_60.00"  86.62  1384 1456 1600 1816  768 769 772 795  -HSync +Vsync
```

5. From the previous result copy what is in front of `Modeline`, (in this case `"1384x768_60.00"  86.62  1384 1456 1600 1816  768 769 772 795  -HSync +Vsync`) and use that as a parameter to `xrandr --newmode` command. For example, in this case, we'll have to run in the server `xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"  85.86  1368 1440 1584 1800  768 769 772 795  -HSync +Vsync`
6. In 5 we've created a newmode in `xrandr`, now we need to add it to the virtual screen, as follows `xrandr --addmode VIRTUAL1 "1368x768_60.00"` (please remember to use your own newly created mode name, which is the value including quotes in 5).
7. Run `x11vnc -usepw -nocursorshape -nocursorpos -noxinerama -solid -repeat -forever -clip CLIENT_WIDTHxCLIENT_HEIGHT+SERVER_WIDTH+0`. As an example: `x11vnc -usepw -nocursorshape -nocursorpos -noxinerama -solid -repeat -forever -clip 1368x768+1920+0`. This will create a VNC server in port `5900` you can connect to.
8. Lastly, connect to the server from you other computer (or any VNC client, recommended `krdc` for linux machines). You should be able to enjoy your extended screen now.

### Notes and considerations:

- In step 8, with krdc, it is recommended to use the "Medium Quality" option, even if you are on cable: both the "Low" and "High" quality options produce errors.
- I tried this over a WiFi network and it works properly, however on cable it's smoother.
- I had problems when starting the VNC server in step 7, the screen started to flicker and I couldn't see what I was doing on the screen. To fix this, I connected via the VNC server (the extended screen already works at this point), opened the `Displays` tool (the one that comes with the system where you can see the displays that are connected) and `Unify Outputs` then `Break Unified Outputs`
  (an example of this option in Kubuntu is shown below). Then everything worked.

[image: Unify Outputs]

Comment: what is gtf ? sudo apt install gtf didn't find anything, and it seems too short an acronym to find by googling.

Comment: Hi, GTF is a tool for calculating VESA GTF modes http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/gtf.1.html. Please check if you have it installed already by issuing `man gtf` in a terminal.