# Extend laptop using a raspberry pi

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, raspberrypi, remote-access, xserver

I have a laptop running on Ubuntu 20.04 that only have one HDMI port and no thunderbolt one and I would like to add a third monitor to my configuration.

I thought about using a raspberry pi as a remote controller for the third screen and extend my laptop screen on it. What I mean by extend my screen is that I would like to have a real third screen, not a duplicate display of what is on my main laptop screen.

I tried to use xdmx and the following command:

```
startx -- /usr/bin/X11/Xdmx :1 -display 192.168.0.43:0 -display 192.168.0.24:0 -ignorebadfontpaths +xinerama
```

where `192.168.0.43` is my laptop adress and `192.168.0.24` is the raspberry one.

running this command I encounter the following error:

```
_XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
_XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running(EE)
```

Which is to be expected as I'm using the default desktop environment for Ubuntu 20.04.

My question is, what is the best way to obtain the desired result?

I think that it might be possible to create a new gnome-session so that a start up, using the command above or a similare one, it creates an xserver session and extend the screen to the raspberry pi considering that the pi is always up and running and if not it switches back to the default configuration, but I don't know how to do that.

I'm open to all suggestions and remarks but if possible I would like to keep the Gnome desktop as I'm use to it.

Comment: Hi, please refer to this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1312338/155835

Comment: Hi, I tried this solution already and it did not work for me as ```VIRTUAL1``` is not defined in step 6), and i could not get what it was refering to

Comment: It is one of the available displays in your system, you can try and run `xrandr` and see the displays available, then replace `VIRTUAL1` with any of those, e.g. `DP1`, let us know if this works for you

Comment: Yes you're right, i replaced ```VIRTUAL1``` ```eDP-1-1``` (which is my laptop screen) and it worked but this is only streaming my laptop screen onto the second screen, where i would like to have a totaly new screen

Comment: Ok, that is a great step, now what you can do to extend the screen is to actually select the displays or monitors (as shown in the picture in that answer) and set them up to separate the screens, not to duplicate them... Again let us know how do you do